# Brightway2: difference in calculation time between "aggregate LCI" ecoinvent version and "unit" ecoinvent version

Tags: brightway

I am curious as to what explains the significant difference in calculation time for a random process using the "aggregate LCI" (or "system" as it is sometimes called) and the "unit" version of ecoinvent 3.4 with Brigthway2.

Intuitively, I expected faster calculation times with the aggregate LCI version. But it turns out that using the unit version of ecoinvent is about 20 times faster.

What is the reason for that? The following code (10 iterations) gives 76 seconds for the aggregate LCI version and 3.7 seconds for the unit version.

```
def lca_road():
    lca = bw.LCA({eidb.random():1}, ("IPCC 2013", "climate change", "GWP 
    100a"))
    lca.lci()
    lca.lcia()
    lca.score
timeit.timeit(lca_road, number=10)
```

Therefore, are there benefits in using the aggregate LCI version of ecoinvent? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes much longer to build the biosphere matrix for the aggregate version, as it has many more numbers. I wouldn't ever use the aggregate version, but I can imagine that the sparse matrix fill rate would go up from around 2% to close to 100%. This easily explains the time difference, as solving the matrix equation is now less than 50% of the total calculation time. If you insist on using the aggregated results, then split off the relevant activities into a new database.